# How does RecyclerView gets 1 extra View from Adapter when we scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

Snap 1:13 Views when Activity Starts. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoDY2.jpg
Snap 2:14 Views 1 at top + 1 at bottom. https://i.stack.imgur.com/barIm.jpg
i am kinda new to android and trying to understand the RecyclerView.
What a Recycler does is when a view goes out of the activity while scrolling it calls the onBindViewHolder which binds the new data to the existing view which just went out of the frame of activity. but while we scroll the activity, there comes a time when we can still see the view which is going out of the frame of activity (Crime #8 in Snap 2) and can also see the new view which is gonna be created by using the viewholder of the Crime # 8 in this case (i.e. Crime #21 in Snap 2). So i am confused that if the previous viewholder(Crime #8) haven't been reused yet how is the new viewholder created(Crime #21).?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqBlYJTfLP4

Watch that video completely. Its a pretty good explanation

Comment: It doesn't reuse view holders.  IT reuses views.  ANd it creates new ones as necessary to fill itself.  So if at start your recycler view has room for two views and as it scrolls it has room for 3, it will create a new view (with associated view holder) for the third view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't delete the old one until it really doesn't need it anymore

Use the `getItem()` ovverriden method to understand when a new item is being created :)

Comment: Okay, i get it that it wont ask the adapter to fill in the new info until it doesn't need the previous ViewHolder anymore. so does that mean it is asking the Adapter to make an extra ViewHolder every time we scroll.?

Comment: Kind of. Let's say you were scrolling downwards and you can see slots 3-9... It will (I don't know exactly how many it will load), but it will pre-load,let's say, slots 10-12 into memory, but it will keep slots 0-2 until it needs to free up memory.